# At what requested disk size does Amazon RDS use striping?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

From the Amazon RDS FAQ Page
http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/

"Depending on the size of storage requested, Amazon RDS automatically stripes across multiple EBS volumes to enhance IOPS performance"

What disk size do I need to request to trigger disk striping? I've only heard rumors of 300GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a conversation with upper management at AWS regarding this. Here is the direct answer provided by them.

> You will realize improvements with RDS throughput by scaling storage as high as 500GB, and this effect starts at a level well under 100GB (ie: striping occurs at a far lower level than 300GB).
>   The most important factor in realizing this throughput potential is the instance class. Specifically, the following instance classes are considered High I/O instances:
>
> m1.xlarge
>
> m2.2xlarge
>
> m2.4xlarge
>
> These instances have large network bandwidth available to them, so the upgrade that you mentioned on stackoverflow (to the m2.2xlarge instance) was likely the main reason you saw a leap in throughput. If you stripe your current storage as high as 500GB, this will continue to increase. With provisioned IOPS support for RDS (PIOPS-announced last night), throughput will now scale linearly all the way to 1TB.
>
> With PIOPS, the throughput rate you can expect is currently associated with the amount of allocated storage. For Oracle and MySQL databases, you will realize a very consistent 1,000 IOPS for each 100GB you allocate – resulting in a potential throughput max of 10K IOPS. The (current, temporary) downside is that you will need to unload/load data to migrate an existing app to the PIOPS RDS.

Comment: This is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked 300gb triggers back-end striping

Comment: Is this referenced anywhere? How did you check? I would just like to somehow confirm this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986568/which-rds-instance-type-has-better-io-extra-large-db-instance-or-high-memory-ex  I found that article just now, but mainly that is from memory of doing it. You can do a simple test is my guess with iostat and just dd a file til it is 300 gb and see how much faster it is. I don't think Amazon has this documented anywhere

Comment: For those curious - I increased my RDS size to the m2.2xlarge (34GB Ram) and increased the disk size to 350GB. I have sustained 2,000+ write ops/sec. InnoDB on a production site.

Comment: On an m1.large with 100GB of storage we typically could reach 1000 write iops.  When we doubled the storage size to 200GB we're now getting over 2000 write iops.  My guess is its somewhere in between 100 and 200GB because nothing else changed on our instance.  HTH

Answer (score 1):

As of September 2023, this only happens with gp3 volumes.

- MariaDB, MySQL, and PostgreSQL: 400 GiB and higher
- Oracle: 200 GiB and higher

You can now see this information on the [Amazon RDS DB instance storage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com//AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#Concepts.Storage.GeneralSSD.gp3) page

> For every RDS DB engine except RDS for SQL Server, when the storage size for gp3 volumes reaches a certain threshold, the baseline storage performance increases to 12,000 IOPS and 500 MiB/s. This is because of volume striping, where the storage uses four volumes instead of one. RDS for SQL Server doesn't support volume striping, and therefore doesn't have a threshold value.

Answer (score 0):

I was told recently by an AWS engineer on an architecture review that 100GB will trigger EBS striping